# c++ best way to call function with const char* parameter type

Tags: c++, function, pointers, char, parameter-passing

what is the best way to call a function with the following declaration

```
string Extract(const char* pattern,const char* input);
```

i use

```
string str=Extract("something","input text");
```

is there a problem with this usage

should i use the following

```
char pattern[]="something";
char input[]="input";
//or use pointers with new operator and copy then free?
```

the both works but i like the first one but i want to know the best practice.

Comment: The problem with string literals is that they aren't writable, so you can't pass them as `char *`. It's however fine to pass them as `const char *`.

Comment: @NiklasB.: You can pass them as `char*` (but it's deprecated and yields undefined behavior if they are modified).

Comment: @Philipp: Yeah, let's just say one should not do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method, i.e. passing them literally in, is usually preferable.

There are occasions though where you don't want your strings hard-coded into the text. In some ways you can say that, a bit like magic numbers, they are magic words / phrases. So you prefer to use constant identifier to store the values and pass those in instead.

This would happen often when:

- `1`. a word has a special meaning, and is passed in many times in the code to have that meaning.

or

- `2`. the word may be cryptic in some way and a constant identifier may be more descriptive

Comment: thanks, i knew about c++ performance and clearing memory and its not like .NET so i wanted to make sure

Answer (score 6):

A literal string (e.g. `"something"`) works just fine as a `const char*` argument to a function call.

Comment: That's good as long as the function doesn't modify the string. Passing a literal to e.g. the dest argument of strcat() would cause problem though.

Comment: @AlexandreJasmin `strcat`'s first parameter is `char *`, so a string literal is an invalid argument (and will make the compiler complain). Its second parameter is `const char *`, and passing a string literal is not a problem.

Comment: If the parameter is marked `const char*`, then the function should not modify the string--that's the whole point of the `const` annotation.  Of course, the function could do so anyway--and then it would be a violation of its expressed contract.

Comment: @hvd: Binding a string literal to `char*` is _not_ invalid – it is deprecated and often generates a warning, but it is legal C++.

Comment: @Philipp Not anymore, you're thinking of the old C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you plain to have duplicates of the same strings, or alter those strings, I'm a fan of the first way (passing the literals directly), it means less dotting about code to find what the parameters actually are, it also means less work in passing parameters.

Seeing as this is tagged for C++, passing the literals directly allows you to easily switch the function parameters to `std::string` with little effort.